# How do I target the nearest enemy?

Tags: x-rebirth

In X Rebirth, what is the key I can use to target the nearest enemy?  I can't seem to find it in the control settings.

Comment: Have you tried Shift+T?

Comment: @kotekzot yea, that's the first thing I tried, doesn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Patch 1.24 (2014-02-04) added new functions:

> Manual target control with keys for target nearest crosshair, closest enemy and next/previous target. Further improvements planned.

Closest enemy can be selected by <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, object near target reticle can be selected with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> with default key bindings.

Outdated answer:

There is no in-game button for it at the moment, Egosoft promised to make it future patches.

But there is mod [Targeting UI Extension now with External Camera](http://forum.egosoft.com/viewtopic.php?t=353669).

> Currently (this will change soon), Rebirth has no good way of targeting enemy ships. This mod, extends the UI by adding a targeting menu with keyboard selectable commands.
>
> In addition, one of the commands will trigger an external camera view of the selected target. The duration of the full-screen view is 5 seconds and can be repeated for extended viewing.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment, there is unfortunately no such setting in the game.

We gonna have to wait for EGOSOFT to put it in.

Comment: hrm... that's disappointing

Comment: @MrUniverse i'm willing to give them some time to sort this out, but yea, so far its super annoying.  For instance, why does my ship speed drop to 0 when I turn to the side to pull up a sector map?

Comment: The devs on the forums have confirmed that it will be put in asap. I am gonna update when it happened.